# Finding combining diacritics for character at point in emacs

Tags: emacs, unicode, character

I am writing a function which returns linguistic information about the character at point. This is easy for pre-composed characters. However, I wish to account for diacritics. I believe these are referred to as "marks" or "combining characters" in Unicode (cf. plane U+0300 - U+036F).

For example, to place the centralization diacritic (U+0306) on the character e:

```
e C-x 8 <RET> 0306 <RET>
```

Run `C-u C-x =` on the resulting character and you will see something like "Composed with the following character(s) ̆ "

Functions such as `following-char` unfortunately only return the base character, i.e. "e", and ignore any combining diacritics. Is there any way to get these?

**EDIT**: slitvinov pointed out that the resulting glyph consists of two characters. If you place point before the glyph created by the above code, and execute `(point)` before and after running `forward-char`, you will see point increase by 2. I figured I could hack a solution through this behaviour, but it appears that inside a `progn` statement (or function definition), `forward-char` only moves point forward by one... try it in a `defun` or with `(progn (forward-char) (point))`. Why might this be?

Answer (score 2):

I think `diacritic e` is treated as two characters. I put this combination in the file
`e(diacritic e)e`.

```
ĕee
(char-after 1)
(char-after 2)
(char-after 3)
(char-after 4)
```

It gives me.

```
101 101 774 101
```

And 774 is a decimal form of 0306.

Comment: Good catch. If I create ĕ using the diacritic U+0306, place point before the resulting character, and execute `forward-char`, point increases by two. There is an issue with this in a function, however, see my edit.